# Call dataset from dictionary in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, foreach, dataset

How do I call a data set from a dictionary inside of a foreach loop? In the code below .Rows doesn't exist and the dataset is null in the foreach loop.

```
public class dictWITHdataset
{
    public dictWITHdataset()
    {
        DataSets = new Dictionary<string, DataSet>();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, DataSet> DataSets { get; private set; }

    public DataSet readrows(DataSet dataset)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM test.dbo.test";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

I later try to call the dataset from a dictionary in a foreachloop but it claims Rows does exist and its null.

```
dictWITHdataset dict = new dictWITHdataset();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
dict.DataSets("Dictionary1",data) //not sure if correct way to call data set
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in  dict.DataSets["Dictionary1"].Rows)
{
    @:row["id"] + " " + row["name"];
}
```

Comment: You have not called readrows in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to call dict.readrows call, thus it only adds an empty dataset. Also, readrows does not need to take a parameter, you can create it in the function.

```
dictWITHdataset dict = new dictWITHdataset();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
dict.DataSets("Dictionary1",dict.readrows(data)) 
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in  dict.DataSets["Dictionary1"].Rows)
{
    @:row["id"] + " " + row["name"];
}
```

Comment: It still says Rows doesn't exist. Could you give me an example of the parameter as a function? I still do not see where I would specify the SQL query for each dataset.

Comment: Do you want your dictionary has the query string as a key and resulting dataset as value?

Comment: To use .Rows, wouldn't I need Datasets.Tables["tablename"] first? How do I avoid the tablename and just use my dataset and dictionary?